# Swipe to dismiss causing inflateexception and illegalstateexception?

Tags: android, swipe, android-sqlite, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement swipe to dismimss in my app's listfragment's list items. I'm using Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroids backport of Roman Nurik's code. However, when I add it into my fragment's onCreate(), I'm getting an inflateexception and an illegalstateexception regarding the getListView() method for the second exception. 
Here is my ListFragment:

```
package com.example.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

/**
 * A list fragment representing a list of Courses. This fragment also supports
 * tablet devices by allowing list items to be given an 'activated' state upon
 * selection. This helps indicate which item is currently being viewed in a
 * {@link CourseDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
 * interface.
 */
public class CourseListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelper;

private static String courseName;
ArrayList<String> courseItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public CourseListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    courseItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, courseItems);
    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //The problem starts here
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    getListView(),
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.OnDismissCallback() {
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                removeCourse(adapter.getItem(position).toString());
                                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
    getListView().setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
        courseItems.add(courseName);
    }
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addCourse() {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
    courseItems.add(courseName);
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeCourse(String deletedCourse) {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
        if (deletedCourse.equals(courseName)) {
            db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID + "=" + 
        db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,new String[]{DbHelper.C_ID},null,null,null,null,null),null);
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(null);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

public void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

And here is my logcat:

```
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sample/com.example.sample.CourseListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.sample.CourseListActivity.onCreate(CourseListActivity.java:55)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.sample.CourseListFragment.onCreate(CourseListFragment.java:96)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
12-04 16:09:30.155: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 19 more
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing to much in OnCreate() - your Fragment's view's are not yet initialized and you are trying to get ListView. Try to use OnViewCreated() or OnActivityCreated() callback.

Comment: Could I also use onCreateView or onAttach or even onViewCreated?

Comment: or should I define a method inside the fragment that is called after the oncreate in the activity?

Comment: If you want to use getListView() call it OnViewCreated or latter lifecycle callbacks.
Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating